# How to register my visual studio extension to run events?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I have a visual studio extension and I want it to run another executable before the program itself is running without debugger (when the program runs with a certain configuration).
how can I do that?

I managed to do that when the program is being **debugged** - I used DTE.Events.DebuggerEvents interface. is there a similar event for running the program without debugger?

```
private static void EventsRegistering()
{
    DTE2 visualStudioInstance;
    debuggerEvents = visualStudioInstance.Events.DebuggerEvents;
    debuggerEvents.OnEnterRunMode += DebuggerEvents_OnEnterRunMode;
}
```

Just to be clear - I don't want it to run with every **build** of the program, just for every **run**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subscribe to DTE.Events.CommandEvents.OnBeforeExecute and detect when a command name is Debug.StartWithoutDebugging. See for example [Monitor commands execution](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/extensions.html#CommandEvents).

Comment: Thank you. Had a hard time finding it myself.